# normal vector after transformation

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, differential-geometry

Let $E$ subset of $\mathbb{R^n}$ such that $E$ has smooth boundary. If $F:\mathbb{R^n }\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ is a diffeomorphism and $G = F^{-1}$ its inverse. Let $\nu_{F(E)}(z)$ be the normal vector of $F(E)$ at $y \in \partial F(E)$. I'm trying to understand why
$$\nu_{F(E)}(z) = \frac{\nabla G(z)^*\nu_E(G(z))}{|\nabla G(z)^*\nu_E(G(z))|}.$$
Here I believe $\nabla G(z)^*$ is the adjoint of the linear operator $\nabla G(z)$.

My attempt:
If $x \in \partial E$ and $\phi:U\subset \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $\{ y \in U \,| \phi(y)=0\} = \partial E \cap U$ then
$$\nu_E(x) =\frac{ \nabla \phi(x)}{|\nabla \phi(x)|} .$$
Now $\phi\circ G: F(U) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ I believe gives the boundary of $F(E)$ near $F(x)=z$ then
$$\frac{\nabla(\phi\circ G)(z)}{|\nabla(\phi\circ G)(z)|}= \nu_{F(E)}(z).$$
By the chain rule $$\nabla(\phi \circ G)(z) = \nabla \phi(G(z)) DG(z)$$
This where I got stuck. Would appreciate the help!

*This is from Maggi's book on finite perimeter page 196.